# call div on link click using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I want to open the div on clicking the link.The link value contains the id of the row of data.I am using ajax to post the data to form.

template.html

```
<div id="authorisedreporter" {% if not registerform.errors %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>
 <form method="post" action="." id="reporter-form">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <table  width="100%">
 <tr>
   <td style="width:100px;">First name:</td><td>{{registerform.first_name}} </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Last name:</td><td>{{registerform.last_name}} </td>
 </tr>
     ''''''''''''''''
     some data here
     '''''''''''''''
 </table></form></div>
```

The above div is in hide condition when page load.I want to open the div when the link is clicked.

```
<td style="width:120px;"><a href="{{ list.0.id }}">{{list.0.first_name|title}} {{list.0.last_name}}</a></td>
```

Need help.

Comment: Add an eventlistener to the a tag and then change the style values from the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use link if it isn't a link, in your case, it's more like `<button>`:

```
<td style="width:120px;"><button id="{{ list.0.id }}" class="js-openDiv">{{list.0.first_name|title}} {{list.0.last_name}}</button></td>
```

Anyway the method is the same, add class `class="js-openDiv"` to your `<a>` or `<button>` and use it as selector in jQuery:

```
$('.js-openDiv').click(function () {
    var this_id = $(this).attr('id');  // the list ID
    // do something with the ID

    $('#authorisedreporter').show();
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you decide to stick with `<a>` tag:

```
<td style="width:120px;"><a id="{{ list.0.id }}" class="js-openDiv" href="#">{{list.0.first_name|title}} {{list.0.last_name}}</a></td>
```

jQuery code would be a bit different:

```
$('.js-openDiv').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var this_id = $(this).attr('id');  // the list ID
    // do something with the ID

    $('#authorisedreporter').show();
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: +1,for your answer.On clicking the link,the div with that id should open,the value in a href="{{ list.0.id }}"> tag is an id,so i want to know how to pass that id to div,so that when this link is clicked,the div should open with the data for the "id" in link.Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use `href` to store the ID, change it to `id`, and I think you should change your whole `<a>` to `<button>` like in my answer. My answer already included how to get that ID.

Comment: You can use custom attribute for a link.
for ex : <a href="yourlink" id="linkId" someId="{{obj.Id}}"></a>
Which you can access by $(this).attr("someId") inside your overwritten click function

Comment: My div should look like this right <div id="authorisedreporter" class="js-openDiv"{% if not registerform.errors %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>

Comment: No, your link (the one that you will click on) should have that class, not your `<div>`.

Comment: ok,implementing button is good thing,since client requirement is with link i am focusing on link,can you tell me how to move with link,instead of button.

Comment: @HieuNguyen,can you please check my another SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883238/ajax-succesfull-call-show-div-with-form-data.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

firstly put  `href="#"` or `href="javasctipt:void(0)` in your anchor tag and put `id` in some other attribute of the anchor tag .
then  the script would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').click(function(){
      $('#authorisedreporter').show();
   });
});
```