# Ajax succesfull call show div with form data

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

views.py

```
def index(request):
    """"""""""""""
    registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    createprofileform = UserCreateProfileForm(request.POST)                            
    if registerform.is_valid() and createprofileform.is_valid():               
        result = registerform.save(commit=False)
        result.set_password(request.POST['password'])        #set member password
        result.username = username               
        result.save()
        member.user_id = user.id
        member.member_id = result.id
        member.save()                                        #new member registration
        member_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=result.id)
        createprofileform = UserCreateProfileForm(request.POST, instance=member_profile)
        createprofileform.save()                             #create member profile                
        createprofileform = UserCreateProfileForm()
        member_save_msg = 'New member has been added.' 
        """"""""""""
    return render(request,'index.html',{ 'registerform': registerform,'createprofile': createprofileform,})
```

index.html

```
{% block main-content %}
<table width="98%" border="0" style="margin-left:0.7%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="rounded_table">
    <tr >
         <td width="50%">Main Account Holder</td><td width="50%">Authorised Reporters</td>
    </tr>
     <tr id="main_account">
          <td width="50%">All data related to main account holder comes here</td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="authorised_reporter">
          <td  width="100%" colspan="2">
           <div id="authorisedreporter" {% if not registerform.errors %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>
                <form method="post" action="." id="reporter-form">{% csrf_token %}
                <table  width="100%">
                  <tr>
                     <td style="width:100px;">First name:</td><td>{{registerform.first_name}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Last name:</td><td>{{registerform.last_name}} </td>
                  </tr>
                         """"""other form fields""""""""
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan=2""><p align="right"><button type="submit" title="Save" >Save <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/button-icon-ir-fwd.png" width="12" height="17" alt="" /></button></p>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  </table></form>
</table>
{%endblock%}
```

The above views.py and index.html is for saving the new user entry.

My html template is divided into 2 section,Main Account Holder tab and Authorised Reporters tab.Main Account Holder tab is for saving profile info and Authorised Reporters tab is for creating new user.on page load Main Account Holder tab will be active and user tab will be hidden.If user tab is selected,Main Account Holder tab will be hidden.Once the user is saved,the user details are displayed below, in below format.

```
{% for list in member_list %}
       <tr class="ir-shade"> 
        <td style="width:120px;"><span><input type="submit" name="delete" value="{{list.0.id}}" class="delete_reporter" /></span><button> id="{{ list.0.id }}" class="openDiv">{{list.0.first_name|title}} {{list.0.last_name}}</button></td>
       <td style="width:410px;"> {{list.0.email}} {{list.1.phone_daytime}} {{list.1.phone_mobile}}</td>
       </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

What i actually want is Onclicking the `<button> id="{{ list.0.id }}" class="openDiv">{{list.0.first_name|title}} {{list.0.last_name}}</button>`  saved user data should shown in same field in editable mode.i am passing the user id in button.On click the button,the data related to user id should shown in editable mode.

js:

```
   $('.openDiv').click(function () {              
    var id = $(this).attr('id');  
    var csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();
    $.ajax({ 
       data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: ('{{csrf_token}}'),                          
            id:id,                
            },
    type:'POST',
    url: '/setting/save-reporter/',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#authorisedreporter').html(data);
    }
  });
 });
```

The below views.py and html are written for showing the saved form instance.Now i can show the saved form instance and i am loading the instance into authorisedreporter div(please check in js and index.html).In this time if i kit save,it is creating new record,it is calling the views.py related to index method.I want to update and not save the record.

save_reporter.html

```
<form method="post" action="." id="{{ id }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table  width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px;">First name:</td><td>{{form.first_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name:</td><td>{{form.last_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Daytime phone:</td><td>{{profile.phone_daytime}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile phone:</td><td>{{profile.phone_mobile}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td><td>{{form.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td><td>{{form.password}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan=2"<p align="right">{% include "buttons/save.html" %}</p></td>
        </tr></table></form>
```

views.py

```
def save_reporter(request):
    user = request.user
    id = request.POST.get('id')
    user = User.objects.get(pk =id)
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user.id)
    form = ReporterRegisterForm(instance=user)
    profileform = ProfilecontactForm(instance=userprofile)               
    return render(request, 'setting/save_reporter.html',
                   {'form': form,
                    'id':id,
                     'profile':profileform
                    })
```

I had explained my current issue i am facing,please have help me in doing this.Thanks

Comment: Any error in console after you click the link?

Comment: Hmm did you turn on `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py`? I can see some error in your view function. Also could you describe what do you expect after clicking the link?

Comment: DEBUG = True in django settings,The link is placed for username.After clicking the link,the related data link first name,last name,email are open in form in edit mode.The link is the saved user profile data  through form using django.Since this window is in div i tried with ajax post.This is to get the data from database in form field in editable mode.

Comment: I updated and explained the current problem i am facing,Can any one help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Let me analyze your JS code a bit, since I can see several errors/mistakes there:

```
$('.openDiv').click(function (e) {       
    e.preventDefault();

    // where is following data taken from? At the point you click the .openDiv link, the form doesn't have any data yet so all of them will be empty string ''
    var csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();
    var id =  $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
    var firstname = $("#"+id).find('#id_first_name').val();
    var lastname = $("#"+id).find('#id_last_name').val();
    var phonedaytime = $("#"+id).find('#id_phone_daytime').val(); 
    var phonemobile = $("#"+id).find('#id_phone_mobile').val();
    var email = $("#"+id).find('#id_email').val();

    // do you use AJAX to get the form or use it to save the form?
    $.ajax({ 
        data: $(this).serialize(), // this is wrong, $(this) is the link object, not a form
        type:'POST',
        url: '/setting/save-reporter/',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#authorisedreporter').html(data);
            $('#authorisedreporter').show();
        }
   });
});
```

Ok as far as I understand, after clicking the link, you are using AJAX to send request to Django view to fetch back the correct instantiated form. So you should:

First, simplify your JS code:

```
$('.openDiv').click(function (e) {       
    e.preventDefault();
    var this_id =  $(this).closest('td').attr('id'); // get the user ID, since that's all you need
    console.log(this_id); // making sure that you get the right ID
    $.ajax({ 
        data: { id: this_id },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/setting/fetch-reporter-form/',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#authorisedreporter').html(data);
            $('#authorisedreporter').show();
        }
   });
});
```

Next, split your old view to several views to focus on what it needs to do (note: you can leave your `index` view as it is now):

```
def fetch_reporter_form(request):
    ''' Change your save_reporter view name to this view '''
    registerform = UserRegisterForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST.get('id', None)
        if id:
            user = get_object_or_404(pk=user.id)
            userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
            registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=user)
            return render(request, 'setting/register_form.html', {
                'user_id': id
                'registerform':registerform
            })
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Request does not contain any ID')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Request is not POST')

def update_reporter(request):
    ''' This function is for update the reporter '''
    registerform = UserRegisterForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
    id = request.POST.get('id', None)
        if id:
            user = get_object_or_404(pk=user.id)
            userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
            registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=user)
            if registerform.is_valid():
                result = registerform.save(commit=False)

                # saving code here ...
                return HttpResponse('Success')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Request does not contain any ID')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Request is not POST')
```

You can see here there are 2 functions: 1 for fetching the right form from AJAX, the other for saving the data via normal form submit. Of course you should make the `urls.py` accordingly, something like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... your code ...
    url(r'^setting/fetch-reporter-form/$', 'yourapp.views.fetch_reporter_form'),
    url(r'^setting/update-reporter/$', 'yourapp.views.update_reporter'),
)
```

You might also notice that you should make a new template `setting/register_form.html` that include your registration form HTML only (note: you need a hidden `id` field that was returned by `fetch_reporter_form` view above to identify the form):

```
<form method="post" action="/setting/update-reporter" id="reporter-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ user_id }}" />
    <!-- your code here -->
</form>
```

So the flow is:

1. You go to `index` view. There is several forms to save new reporter, etc. as normal.
2. You click on the `.openDiv` button. It will send the AJAX request above to `fetch_reporter_form` to get the correct form. (Your code is working fine at this point)
3. You click Save button on that form, it will submit the updated data (via POST) to `update_report` view and update the reporter.

I'm just trying to give you the basic idea. The rest is quite straightforward so I guess you can continue easily. Hope it helps!

Comment: Answer updated! Please read each section carefully and you can get the main idea. I can't do your job instead of you so please try your best following my guide.

Comment: I need to load the fetched form data into the form field which is inside the div,how to do that.

Comment: Onclick,hidden div is open but the values in database are not fetched and displayed in form.Any idea where i have to debug.

Comment: Hmm `console.log(data)` in the ajax success, I think the view should be correct but you can do `print registerform` right after `registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=user)` in `fetch_reporter_form` view to debug.

Comment: I am not getting 404 error,i used return HttpResponse('True'),it is returning true but not showing the data in form field

Comment: It means that there isn't `id` in POST request. Hmm you can change the message to Error1 and Error2 and debug from there.

Comment: For fetching and showing the instance of form data,i written a method,i am getting the right id from post,but it is not showing the instance.I updated my tried views.py.Please see my update.

Comment: Sorry I can't help further if you are not taking my advice and still trying to use one view for everything. It's very messy and hard to debug with your current code.

Comment: I updated my question,in js line no 12,after sucessfull ajax call i am trying to load the div with the save_reporter.html.I am getting 404 error in console.Can you tell me how to do this.

Comment: You have to switch it back to `function (data) { $('#authorisedreporter').html(data); .... }`. Use `load()` is wrong.

Comment: If i save the form instance it is saving but creating new record instead of updating.I written save code in another method.

Comment: why don't you split your view into 2 functions like my guide? it's way easier to debug that way.

Comment: Earlier i was used one view for showing the form data and other view for saving the data,but i want to update the form data  instead of saving.So i merged both in single view.I can separate into 2 views.Want to know how to perform form data  updation using another view.

Comment: You can use the field for saving to update the data, don't merge them into one view so you can't debug where is the error

Comment: To save new record,i have another view and that view is only meant for saving new data alone.Currently,for showing the form instance i had written another view,and returning the HttpResponse in save_reporter.html.Now,the response in save_reporter.html are loaded in authorisedreporter div,which is in index.html.Authorisedreporter div contain the same form field as in save_reporter.html.Since,the save_reporter.html response are loaded in authorisedreporter div,which is in index.html,if i click save it is creating the new record.This is the problem here,need your guidence to fix this.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35350/discussion-between-user2086641-and-hieu-nguyen

Answer (score 1):

Let me resume what you are doing:

```
$.ajax({ 
    data:{
        /* ... */
    },
    type:'POST',
    url: '/report/save_reporter/',
    success: function() {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Here you setup an Ajax asynchronous query to post data to the server. When the query reaches the server, if it doesn't crash, the `success:` callback is called and javascript does nothing (`return true;`).

```
$('#authorisedreporter').show();
```

Here, you show an HTML node **before the asynchronous Ajax query ends** (succeeds or fails). To show the element after the Ajax query is done, put this code inside the `success:` or `error:` callback.

Finally, if you count your `(`, `)`, `{` and `}` you will see than `$('#authorisedreporter').show();` is outside of the click callback. Therefore, if it is out of the document ready callback, it will have no effect.

So the right Javascript code should be (I think):

```
$('.openDiv').click(function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();          
    var id = $(this).attr('id');  
    var firstname = $("#"+id).find('#id_first_name').val();    
    var phonemobile = $("#"+id).find('id_phone_mobile').val();    
    $.ajax({ 
        data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token,
            edit_reporter:true,
            id:id,
            first_name:firstname,               
            phone_mobile:phonemobile,
        },
        type:'POST',
        url: '/report/save_reporter/',
        success: function() {
            $('#authorisedreporter').show();
        }
   });
});
```

**EDIT:**

About your view.py, you save a UserProfile but do not return anything to the client browser. Nothing.

```
def save_reporter(request):
    user=User.objects.get(user=user) # you should use django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404
    userprofile = Userprofile.objects.get(user=user) # same comment
    if request.method == 'POST':
        registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST,instance=user)
        createprofileform = UserCreateProfileForm(request.POST,instance=userprofile)
        # you create 2 forms above, but don't use them. Is it normal ?!
        # you should do loops "if registerform .valid(): ... else: ..." and use it. Same for the 2nd form
        if 'edit_reporter' in request.POST:
            first_name=request.POST.get('first_name') # can be None
            phone_mobile = request.POST.get('phone_mobile') # can be None      
            user = User.objects.get(pk=user)
            user.first_name = first_name            
            user.save() # put it inside a try/except statment
            userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=user) # use get_or_404
            userprofile.phone_mobile = phone_mobile 
            userprofile.save() # put it inside a try/except statment
    return HttpResponse() # this returns an empty html page, do you want to return the form here ?
```

Comment: Can you check my views.py code which is for saving and showing the instance data in form which inside the div.

Comment: See the EDIT. So you want your Ajax query to return data ? Would it be the form rendered as HTML ? Some JSON data ? A raw text ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any error message returned from the server:

```
$.ajax({ 
    // ...
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

});

**Edit**:

You don't pass the user id when you submit the form. Try doing something like:

```
<form ...>
   <!-- //.. -->
   {{ form.id.as_hidden }}
</form>
```

Comment: can you check my update 2 in question and guide me how to perform form updation instead of saving the data.

Comment: The id has to go as a form element. Which it will if you put `{{ form.id.as_hidden }}` anywhere inside the form tags.

Comment: I am passing the id as id={{id}}.I am able to show the form instance but not able to save and update the form instance,need some idea how to do.

Comment: And you shouldn't be doing that. Do what I say above instead. And does {{ id }} have a value in the rendered form?

Comment: Yes,id have the value in render form(user table id)

Comment: That's good that it has a value. But in order for it to show up in `request.POST` it needs to be within the `<form>` tags (I think). So either put what I mention above or manually do `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ id }}">`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35421/discussion-between-user2086641-and-dan-klasson)